Determine the functions $f:\mathbb{N}^*\to \mathbb{N}^* $ with the property that $f(m+n)=f(m)+f(n)$
The problem

Let the nonempty sets $A,B$ be with the property that $A \cup B= \mathbb{N}^* $ and
they are disjoint. Determine the functions $f:\mathbb{N}^* \to \mathbb{N}^* $ with the property that
$f(m+n)=f(m)+f(n)$, for any pair $(m,n) \in (A \times A) \cup (B \times B)$.

My idea
So, I thought of taking the case where both are zero. Then, we get the fact that $f(0)=0$.
Another interesting thing I discovered is that if we take $n \to -n$ then we have a periodic function $f(m)=f(m-n)+f(0)=f(m+n)$.
Also $f(2m)=2 \cdot f(m)$.
I don't know what to do forward. Hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

Please define the set $N$.

@N.F.Taussig it is the natural numbers set

Why are you writing $\mathbb{N}^$ instead of just $\mathbb{N}$? What does the $$ mean?

@JMM In France at least, it means $\mathbb{N} \ {0}$. (Yes, 0 is a natural number). However this seems to conflict OP's idea...

Let $\langle A \rangle$ be the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $A$, and define $\langle B \rangle$ similarly. Surely such a map $f$ would extend to a homomorphism $\langle A \rangle \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, as well as a homomorphism $\langle B \rangle \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. Since $A \cup B = \mathbb{N}^$, the map $f$ uniquely determines a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. So aren't we just looking for the maps $\mathbb{N}^ \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^*$ which are restrictions of homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$? Maybe I'm missing something here.

@JMM Yes you are missing that generating sets don't have to be free. So it's not clear at all if the homomorphisms can be defined as you say.

I'll assume $\mathbb{N}^*=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, although including $f(0)=0$ makes no difference to the problem.
An obvious family of solutions is $f(x)=ax$ for $a\in\mathbb{N}^*$.
Alternatively, assume that $f$ is a different solution. Then, let $a=f(1)$, and let $n$ be the smallest number for which $f(n)\not=an$. By assumption, such an $n$ must exist, and $n>1$. I will show that no such solution exists.
Write $x\sim y$ to denote that $(x,y)\in A\times A\cup B\times B$, and $x\nsim y$ otherwise: ie to indicate if they are in the same set. Thus, the rule becomes that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for any $x\sim y$.
We may first note that $f(2^rx)=2^rf(x)$ for any $r,x$. From this follows that $n$ must be odd, otherwise we would have $f(n)=2f(n/2)=an$ since $n/2<n$ makes $f(n/2)=an/2$.
From here on, I recommend trying to solve the rest on your own as soon as you have seen the first idea that's new to you.
For $k<n$, we must have $k\nsim n-k$, otherwise $f(n)=f(k)+f(n-k)=an$: ie, one of the numbers $k, n-k$ is in $A$ and the other is in $B$.
If $n-2k\sim n$ for some $k<n/2$, that makes $f(n)+f(n-2k)=f(2n-2k)=2f(n-k)=2a(n-k)$ which would make $f(n)=an$ as $f(n-2k)=a(n-2k)$. Hence, $n-2k\nsim n$ for all $k<n/2$: ie, odd numbers less than $n$ are not in the same set as $n$. However, since $2k\nsim n-2k$, that makes $2k\sim n$ for every $k<n/2$: ie, all even numbers less than $n$ are in the same set as $n$.
Next, we have two alternatives for $n+1$:
i) Assume $n+1\sim n$. Since we also have $n-1\sim n$ since $n-1$ is even, we get $2f(n)=f(2n)=f(n+1)+f(n-1)=2f(\frac{n+1}{2})+2f(\frac{n-1}{2})=2an$ which contradicts $f(n)\not=an$.
ii) Assume $n+1\nsim n$. Then, using $1\nsim n$ since 1 is odd, $1$ and $n+1$ must be in the same set: ie, $n+1\sim 1$. Hence, $f(n+2)=f(n+1)+f(1)=2f(\frac{n+1}{2})+f(1)=a(n+1)+a$. However, we also have $f(n+2)=f(n)+f(2)=f(n)+2a$ since $2\sim n$, which again makes $f(n)=an$.

@vuur: Thanks for the suggestions and corrections. Have updated the answer.

Natural follow-up: Are there nontrivial solutions for three colors?

@SeanEberhard: I've given it some thought, but haven't really gotten anywhere.

Why is $1 \not\sim n$?

@MartinBrandenburg As $n$ is odd, $n - 2k \nsim n$ for $k<n/2$ means that all odd numbers less than $n$ lie in a set different from $n$, in particular $1$.

@MartinBrandenburg: See the reply by vuur. I've added and highlighted a comment on this now to make it more clear.
